# WP7 binding from ListBoxItem style to other than listbox itemsource property

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, binding

I have property in viewmodel like this:

```
public class TestObject
{
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public IList<Items> { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

listbox in view like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TestObject.Items}" ....
```

and listbox style like this:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
           ...
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Duration="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame  KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{**Binding to TestObject.Color ???}**" />
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Duration="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame  KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{**Binding to TestObject.Color ???}**"/>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

...

So please... how can i binding out of ItemsSource binding?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the control style part of your question... but generally if I want to bind to something outside of the current item, then I use an `ElementName` trick to make it work - e.g.

```
 <Grid Name='RootLayout'>
     <ListBox ItemsSource='{Binding Items}'>
          <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="{Binding DataContext.PriorityColor, ElementName=RootLayout}" />
               </DataTemplate>
          </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     </ListBox>
 </Grid>
```

---

I also generally wouldn't include Color directly in my ViewModel, but would instead use a converter like:

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="{Binding DataContext.Priority, ElementName=RootLayout, Converter={StaticResource PriorityToColorConverter}}" />
```

This is especially helpful if you are doing cross-platform viewmodels - as the Color and Brush classes aren't shared across WP7 and WinRT, let alone across MonoTouch and MonoDroid too.

Comment: Could it be impossible?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440292/using-templatebinding-in-objectanimationusingkeyframes

So another flow: How make selected item of listbox custom styled?